# How to "flush tor circuit"

Tags: linux, security, privacy, tor

On Windows I have used XBBrowser, which provides a custom version of Firefox suited to using Tor.

XBBrowser provides a button, flush tor circuit, which will setup an entirely new connection and exit node.

I am wondering how to do the equivalent thing on Linux. ALl I can do is restart tor, which does not seem to make any difference.

So, on Linux, how would I flush the circuit?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969958/how-to-change-tor-exit-node-programmatically || http://superuser.com/questions/449060/tor-how-to-have-different-ip-address-for-every-page-request

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to enable the control port in torrc

It is also important to set a password for the control port with tor --hash-password password

You can then connect to the control port and issue a NEWNYM commands.

```
printf "AUTHENTICATE \"password\"\r\nSIGNAL NEWNYM\r\n" | nc 127.0.0.1 9051
```

Comment: Does this really close all circuits? On Windows at least, if I do "SIGNAL NEWNYM" followed by "getinfo circuit-status" I often find old open circuits. I have to use the "closecircuit" command to be sure all circuits are closed.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [Vidalia](http://www.torproject.org/vidalia/) GUI, you can use the Network map to close all circuits. It's not as fast, but does the same thing.

Comment: Nope, no GUI...