# Tor provider point

Tags: networking, port, privacy, tor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to “flush tor circuit”](https://superuser.com/questions/138262/how-to-flush-tor-circuit)

Hello, I have a tor runned on my computer. In Vidalia (gui-frontend) there is a button: 'Use a new identity'. This will change last point of connecting in Tor-network. Are there any commands which I can send to the 9051 port (configure-port) to use randomly any another server?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [How to "flush tor circuit"](https://superuser.com/questions/138262/how-to-flush-tor-circuit/139018#139018). This answers describes what you have to send to Port 9051.