# How do I tell tor, from the command-line, to give me a new identity in a Mac?

Tags: command-line, terminal, tor

Is there a way to ask tor/vidalia for a new identity, via the command-line, as opposed to mousing to the icon, bringing up the menu, and clicking the option there?

I'm running Mac OSX 10.6 and 10.7 with the stable install 0.2.2.32-0.2.14.

Comment: Actually, this is probably a dupe of http://superuser.com/questions/138262/how-to-flush-tor-circuit, since you can run a similar command on Mac OSX.

Comment: Linux: https://askubuntu.com/questions/499995/change-ip-address-which-is-given-by-tor-using-the-terminal

Answer (score 7):

Using this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991639/how-can-i-force-tor-to-use-a-new-identity-without-using-vidalia) answer:

> Open a telnet connection to the control port of your Tor service and send it SIGNAL NEWNYM.

Comment: More details please, I have the same issue.
How do i go about finding the control port for Tor
Would that be the http port 8118 or the Socks port 9050?

Comment: Neither - the control port is set in your `torrc` file, or you can specify it on the command line when you start tor.